# Use switch to take in unknown data types, issue with taking in an object

Tags: javascript, object, switch-statement

In the below code I am trying to make a switch statement that takes in the following inputs: 34, '34', {input: 34}, hello, ["hello"]

and returns the number 34 within each input, the cases I need to have are:

```
If given a number, return the number
If given a string, convert it to a number and return the result
If given an object, return the value of the input property
Otherwise, throw an error: "Unexpected data type"
```

I am having an issue with the object input. Thank you so much!

```
function parseNumber(unknown) {
  switch(unknown) {
    case 34:
        return unknown;
    
    case '34':
        return parseInt(unknown);
      
    case unknown.input: 
        return unknown.input;
    
    default:
        throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking exactly for 34? The question does not see like you should be checking for 34 exactly. Switch also seems to be a poor choice for this.

Comment: It's a requirement for the question. I don't have control over what it should check for. It ask to match the cases for the number 34.

Comment: The numbers passed in are 34..... I do not think it means to match 34 `"If given a number, return the number"`

Comment: @Shuken Those are just examples of the different types, not the only possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` result in the switch cases, to determine the output:

```js
/*If given a number, return the number
If given a string, convert it to a number and return the result
If given an object, return the value of the input property
Otherwise, throw an error: "Unexpected data type"*/


function parseNumber(unknown) {
  const type = typeof unknown;
  //typeof null is object so throwing error
  if (!unknown) throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  //for non numeric strings throwing error
  if (type === "string" && Object.is(+unknown, NaN)) throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  //typeof Array is object so excluding arrays
  if (Array.isArray(unknown)) throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  if (type === "object" && !unknown.hasOwnProperty("input")) throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  
  switch (type) {
    case "number":
      return unknown;
    case "string":
      return +unknown;
    case "object":
      return unknown.input;
    default:
      throw new Error("Unexpected data type");
  }
}
console.log(parseNumber(34));
console.log(parseNumber('34'));
console.log(parseNumber({input: 34}));
//Error cases
try{
console.log(parseNumber("hello"));
}catch(e){console.error(e)}

try{
console.log(parseNumber());
}catch(e){console.error(e)}

try{
console.log(parseNumber(() => "hello"));
}catch(e){console.error(e)}

try{
console.log(parseNumber([34]));
}catch(e){console.error(e)}

try{
console.log(parseNumber({"foo": "bar"}));
}catch(e){console.error(e)}
```

Comment: `case "object" && !Array.isArray(unknown):` <-- um...., that would be `case true` or `case false`.....

Comment: @epascarello may bad, fixed it.

Comment: @FullstackGuy Thank you, that great. I had the wrong type of logic on how I was using the switch, and this really helps.